# forward slash in menu stops active link from working - javascript controlled

Tags: javascript, menu

I'm using a JS to activate the active link within a menu.

Problem is, my CMS places a forward slash before menu items. As soon as it does this, the JS no longer works. If I remove the slash, it works again.

Any ideas how I get it to work with and without the forward slash?

Here's a page I'm testing it on: http://www.sunseedor...k/products1.php

JS is:

$(function(){

var $page = jQuery.url.attr("file");

$('ul.top-nav li a').each(function(){

var $href = $(this).attr('href');

if ( ($href == $page) || ($href == '') ) {

$(this).addClass('on');

} else {

$(this).removeClass('on');

}

});

});

Comment: are you saying that the link originally looks like "linktopage.html" but the CMS changes it to "/linktopage.html"? If not, can you give an example of what a link looks like before and after it is changed?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try this :

```
$(function(){
  var currUrl = window.location.href;
   if(currUrl.substr(-1) == "/")
    jQuery.url.setUrl(currUrl.substr(0,currUrl.length-1));

 var $page = jQuery.url.attr("file");   /* this comes as null
                                           if the URL has ending slash*/

 $('ul.top-nav li a').each(function(){
 var $href = $(this).attr('href');
  if ( ($href == $page) || ($href == '') ) {   $(this).addClass('on'); } 
else {
 $(this).removeClass('on');
 } });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks DhruvPathak, but that doesn't seem to have an impact - http://www.sunseedorganics.co.uk/products2.php

Comment: Thanks Dhruv, but still not working. Am I doing something wrong? http://www.sunseedorganics.co.uk/products3.php